# Connect java application to print server with zpl code

Tags: java, zpl

I have print server URL and i want to connect this print server from my java code.

I am using zpl language for level printing.

I have zpl code as a string and i want my java application to connect this print server using URL and take a print using zpl string.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far and where you failed?

Comment: thanks TobiSH for your comment.
i have one file located to below path in my local.
File file = new File("C:\\Users\\KUSHAL\\Desktop\\Receivint-transaction(print label).zpl")

i am just getting this file from location and inside that file i have zpl label print code.
and i have print server URL through which i will be able to get print label using zpl code.

Comment: Assuming that you are not using any library you just have to open a client socket and send your ZPL commands: https://supportcommunity.zebra.com/s/article/Java-example-for-network-printing?language=en_US

Comment: Thanks for this solution but now i have a requirement to connect printer through print server url and need to send zpl string for label print.
can you please provide the solution that how can i connect printer using print server url with zpl language ?

Comment: this is updated question 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63595753/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-commons-httpclient-httpmethod-while-t