# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/httpclient/HttpMethod while trigger job

Tags: java, zebra-printers, zpl

I am trying to print label using ZPL langugae.
I have print server URL through i can be able to access my printer.

below is my code

```
String templateString = strBuilder.toString();      //this is ZPL language string
String URL= "https://{ip address}/printers/{printer name}";
        
URI printerURI = new URI(url.replace(" ","%20"));
IppPrintService svc = new IppPrintService(printerURI);
DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.BYTE_ARRAY.AUTOSENSE;
Doc myDoc = new SimpleDoc(templateString.getBytes(), flavor, null);
DocPrintJob job = svc.createPrintJob();     
job.print(myDoc, null);    //i am getting error on this line
```

i have included JIPSI jar file in my lib folder.

The exception I get looks like this

```
Exception in thread "main" 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/httpclient/HttpMethod 
    at de.lohndirekt.print.IppRequestCupsImpl.send(IppRequestCupsImpl.java:294) 
    at de.lohndirekt.print.Job.print(Job.java:110) 
    at demo.print1.main(print1.java:44) 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethod 
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) 
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) 
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) 
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: What error do you get? Can you insert the error message + stacktrace

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/httpclient/HttpMethod
 at de.lohndirekt.print.IppRequestCupsImpl.send(IppRequestCupsImpl.java:294)
 at de.lohndirekt.print.Job.print(Job.java:110)
 at demo.print1.main(print1.java:44)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethod
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)

Comment: i am facing above error on this line.
job.print(myDoc, null);

Comment: That looks like you don't have the right libs at your classpath. You need to have "some" apache-commons jar at your classpath

Comment: Hii i have added httpclient jar and some apache-comon jars.
i am running my code as a  run as java application.

Comment: still i am getting the same error

Comment: apache-httpcomponents-httpclient.jar ,
jipsi.jar ,
org-apache-commons-codec.jar ,
org-apache-commons-logging.jar ,
org.apache.commons.beanutils.jar ,
org.apache.commons.collections.jar ,
org.apache.commons.digester_1.8.jar ,
org.apache.commons.io.jar ,

i have above jar in my lib folder

Comment: Can you show how you run it? Could it be that you are using the jars just to compile the code but not to run it?

Comment: Hii , i have added jar in lib folder and also included those jar in right click project -> build path  -> configuration build path

Comment: OK - that includes the jar files to the build process. How do you run your application? Take the resulting jar and then `java -cp ...`?

Comment: i am running my source file by right click and run as java application

Comment: Do you mean in your IDE?